# Input value won't change

Tags: javascript, tampermonkey

I'm having some trouble getting my input value to change when I type a value inside it.

```js
var t = document.createElement('div');

t.innerHTML = '<input type="text" id="myText">';
document.getElementById("news").appendChild(t);
     
var x = document.getElementById("myText").value; //Grabs the value of the input. 
     
t.onchange = function(){myFunction()} //Input. Onchange..
function myFunction() {
  console.log(x); //Logs the value of "x"
}
```

My problem is when I type some string in the input. "Hello world" as a example. It should print "Hello world" to the console. Instead it prints nothing. Just a blank line. How could I make it to print what I type inside the input box?

Using my script.

Comment: We don't have `onchange` on div, it's on input element.

Comment: also define your `x` variable inside function to get synced value else you will always get value which is being evaluated during onload event ( when first time script in loaded )

Comment: T defines the element?

Answer (score 2):

1. The 'change' event fires only when you leave the input field. You probably want an 'input' event here which fires immediately and the listener is registered with `oninput`
2. `x` is a variable that's initialized just once and variables are not bound to the current value of whatever you used to initialize them so you need to read the element's value again
3. bind a function directly to the the event so it can use `this` to access the element directly
4. add the event on the input element, not on the div

---

```
document.getElementById("myText").oninput = myFunction;

function myFunction() {
  console.log(this.value)
}
```

Comment: How could I use "this.value" as a variable.

Comment: So I could do something like. console.log(this);    this would = the value of "this.value" so I could possibly use it with other pieces of code when needed.

Comment: `this` and `this.value` can be used only inside the listener so you need to put all the code that uses the value inside the listener as well.

Answer (score 1):

Since we don't have `onchange` on div, it's on input element.

Difference between **onchange** & **onkeyup**. (MDN)

**onkeyup** — The `keyup` event fires when the user releases a key that was previously pressed.

So, whenever you change value it gets triggered.

**onchange** — change events fire when the user commits a value change to a form control. This may be done, for example, by clicking outside of the control or by using the Tab key to switch to a different control.

So, unless you `tab` or click outside of input your function won't get called.

You should replace your code with following.

```js
var t = document.createElement('div');
t.innerHTML = '<input type="text" id="myText">'

document.getElementById("news").appendChild(t);


var input = document.getElementById('myText');
input.onkeyup = myFunction

function myFunction() {
  var x = document.getElementById("myText").value; //Grabs the value of the input. 
  console.log(x); //Logs the value of "x"
}
```

```html
<div id="news"/>
```

Comment: onkeyup won't run on mouse manipulations like selecting/pasting/cutting via the context menu.